# vb.net ejecutar reporte remoto en aplicacion de escritorio

Tags: vb.net, ssrs

Tengo la siguientes líneas de código, donde estoy intentando ejecutar un reporte y obtener sus parámetros, pero siempre me dice:

> The attempt to connect to the report server failed. Check your connection information and that the report server is a compatible version.

Estas son las líneas:

```
serverReport.ReportServerUrl = New Uri("http://servername/Reports")  'Le doy click aquí y si accedo al reporting service
serverReport.ReportPath = "/carpeta/Carpeta1/carpeta2/carpeta3/Exportar%20reporte"  'Nombre (ruta completa) del reporte
Dim parametros As String = ""
Dim param = serverReport.GetParameters  'Aquí me sale el error, no puedo obtener los parámetros del reporte
```

Es una aplicación de escritorio.

Comment: Hay más fnformación en C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\Reporting Services\LogFiles ?

Comment: yo no tengo acceso al servidor, solo me pasan la direccion del server y el path para ejecutar el reporte.